# Store JSON information within a HTML file or the other way around

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, electron

That title might be a little confusing but I don't know how to put it otherwise. I have some JSON encoded data in a .json-file:

```
{"foo":"bar", "bar":"foo", "far":"boo"}
```

and some HTML content in a .html-file:

```
<h1>I'm a Title</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br>
<img src="./media/foo.png">
```

There is a jQuery script that takes the data from both files (`$.getJSON()` and `$(#div).load()`) and creates a page with some predefined head, uses the html as content and the json data to create some buttons (key=destination & value=name) on there.

Because the project has many of these pages I would love to have only one file that holds both my HTML content AND the JSON data so I had all I needed for one page would be a single file access. So the question really is: **How can I store both JSON and HTML data in one file so jQuery can access, distinguish and process it?**

This is part of an electron application but I'm not sure if that even matters for that question.

Comment: rename the `.json` to `.js`, add a `var links = ` at the beginning, and then you can easily use it inside the js

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for the fast answer! Unfortunately I don't understand. Where does the HTML go? Could you elaborate?

Comment: JSON is an abbreviation for JavaScript Object Notation, so `'{ "a": 1 }'` is a JSON string, `{ "a": 1 }` is just a javascript object. you can just put it inside the script part and work with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the json file assuming it is a json object can be assigned to a javascript variable in the html document in a script tag.

Then to refer to, for example `foo`, you use `theJsonObject.foo`;

With the following javascript snipet you can see inthe browser's console the name of each property an the value.

How you mix this in your current code depends on how you are writting it. But make sure the variable is declared before you use it.

```js
for (let prop in theJsonObject) {  
  console.log( prop + ": " + theJsonObject[prop] );
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      ....
      <script>
         var theJsonObject = {"foo":"bar", "bar":"foo", "far":"boo"};
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      ....
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks very promising. How would I iterate over the keys and values without knowing them in this case?

Comment: In the example, theJsonObject becomes an object with foo, bar, and far properties.

Comment: Use for(variable in object) {}

Comment: Could you provide an example how to get key and value? It just tells me theJsonObject is not defined..

Comment: I added a javascript snippet that shows you how the for in loop works.